# mPDF: Generating pdf file throws a 403 error in live server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mpdf

I am trying to generate a `pdf` file using the `mPDF` library in `php`. This is my code:

Firstly, I am sending a huge load of data which needs to be written into my `pdf` file.

**JS**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/backend_pdfgen/pdfgen.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data:{
       "date": date_splitted[2]+" "+months[date_splitted[1]]+", "+date_splitted[0],
       "pos_news_table": JSON.stringify(pos_links_snaps),
    },
    success:function(response){
        window.open('backend_pdfgen/reports/'+response,"_blank");
    },
    complete:function(){}
})
```

In my `php`, I am generating the `pdf` file like this:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['setAutoTopMargin' => 'stretch','mode' => 'UTF-8']);
    $mpdf->SetTitle("Report (".$_POST["date"].").pdf");
    $mpdf->SetAuthor("Me");
    $mpdf->setHeader('<h1 style="text-align: 
           center; color: rgb(50, 91, 205); font-size: 35px;">
           <u>REPORT TITLE</u></h1>');

    if(isset($_POST["pos_news_table"])){
        $data = json_decode($_POST["pos_news_table"],true);
        foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            $split_val = explode("**",$value);
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr>
                 <td style="border: 3px solid rgb(59, 84, 167); text-align:center; width:140px; height:25px; font-size: 15px;">'.$slno.'</td>
                 <td style="border: 3px solid rgb(59, 84, 167); text-align:center; width:140px; height:25px; font-size: 15px; font-family: freeserif;">'.$split_val[2].'</td>
                 <td style="border: 3px solid rgb(59, 84, 167); text-align:center; width:140px; height:25px; font-size: 15px; font-family: freeserif;">'.$split_val[1].'</td>
                 <td style="border: 3px solid rgb(59, 84, 167); text-align:center; width:140px; height:25px; font-size: 15px;">'.$split_val[0].'</td>
                 <td style="border: 3px solid rgb(59, 84, 167); text-align:center; width:140px; height:25px; font-size: 15px;">'.$split_val[4].'</td></tr>'
            );
         }
     }
     $mpdf->Output("reports/Report (".$_POST["date"].").pdf");
     echo "Report (".$_POST["date"].").pdf";
?>
```

---

When I execute the code in my **live** server, I keep getting *403
Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied!* error in my `Network` console.

But strangely, when I run this same code in my `localhost` server, it works. Why isn't it working in my `live server`?

Comment: Check the file permissions on the directory `reports`

Comment: A 403 for _which_ of the two requests?

Comment: @CBroe, I am only making a single request

Comment: You are making one POST request via AJAX, and then you are making a GET request via window.open.

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue, you could try changing the permissions of the "reports" directory and its contents to 777, which should allow any user to read, write, and execute files in that directory.

Comment: @Stefan: Suggesting setting the permissions to `0777` is bad advice. `0755` should suffice

Comment: @DarkBee, this is just for troubleshoot. I am not suggesting to keep it like that.

Answer (score -2):

It is pretty hard to debug something without access, but what I can tell you is, that you are searching on the wrong place.

I interpret your "in my Network console", as if the first ajax request fails.

As soon as you have differences on evironments, you will have to look at things that change between those.

My ideas are:

- Application configurations (which does not apply to your setup, as you are not using a framework, like symfony in your snipped)
- Webserver configuration: lets say you are using apache or nginx, both could be setup to not be able to execute php files in subfolders for example
- Webserver access on you live server: It could be, that your php file is assigned to another linux user/groups and therefore not able to access/execute the file
- Windows/Linus: linux and windows have other mentalities for accessing files, like case insensitivity for folder name on windows